# Flex-layout breaks while rendering when bootstraps from server-side response

Tags: express, angular-cli, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-flex-layout

Fisrt of all, here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/common": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/compiler": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/core": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/flex-layout": "5.0.0-beta.13",
  "@angular/forms": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/http": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/router": "5.2.8",
  "@angular/service-worker": "5.2.8",
  "@ngrx/effects": "5.2.0",
  "@ngrx/entity": "5.2.0",
  "@ngrx/store": "5.2.0",
  "@ngrx/store-devtools": "5.2.0",
  "@nguniversal/common": "5.0.0-beta.5",
  "@nguniversal/express-engine": "5.0.0-beta.5",
  "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "5.0.0-beta.5",
  "@ngx-meta/core": "5.0.0",
  "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
  "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
  "b64-to-blob": "1.2.19",
  "chart.js": "2.7.2",
  "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
  "core-js": "2.5.3",
  "file-saver": "1.3.8",
  "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
  "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
  "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.0",
  "ngx-cookie-service": "1.0.10",
  "ngx-pipes": "2.1.2",
  "node-fetch": "2.1.1",
  "node-jsencrypt": "1.0.0",
  "rxjs": "5.5.6",
  "tassign": "1.0.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.20"
}
```

I use flex-layout to position elements, so I have imported its server module as it said in [first option](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/guides/SSR.md)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
    TranslatesServerModule,
    FlexLayoutServerModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: AppStorage, useClass: UniversalStorage }
  ],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

and now I receive pretty rendered view when initalizing page with first request:

[image]

Here is everything fine and it works for most cases. But here what will happen if I load the component which got http request in its onInit() method - it breaks for a while:

**FIRST EXAMPLE**
[image]

This happens only after initial load, if the component has guard, effect or some custom service method that triggers http fetching.

Things get even worse when there is some setTimeout or setInterval in the code - it will block server-side execution with neverending timeout and never respond to client. So I wrapped it all with 'isBrowserPlatform' conition and now it is passing server-side execution without any problems, but then somehow on the client it turns into a permanent mess:

**SECOND EXAMPLE**
[image]

Here is the code that breaks it, removing this will fix the issue:

```
if (!environment.isServer) {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(Date.now());
  }, 1000);
}
```

When I inspect broken layout, I see classes like this 'flex-layout-107' everywhere where my flex-layout directives were placed, but no styles are applied to them.

[image]

But I can find all these classes in sources! I wonder why they are not applied though.

[image]

Are there similar cases or am I the only one who is facing this issue?

How can I fix this? I dont want my app to flicker with broken layout while loading or break forever.
I can supply any information if required. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any parent selector for that specific css class?

Comment: it looks like this:
<style class="flex-layout-ssr">
            @media all {
                .flex-layout-1393 {
                    ...styles
                }

No parent selectors specified.